# Install WSL dist on physical drive

Tags: installation, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux

What I know:

- How to install dists manually or from the store, using terminal and such.
- Mounting ext4 physical drives in Windows that WSL can read.

What I don't know, and what I'm asking is how do I install a WSL dist on to a ext4 physical drive? (not using vhdx, in other words)

Here's what I know doesn't work:

- There's no boot system that I know of in WSL, so it doesn't fall in
  the generic virtual computer category. This means you can't boot a
  live cd for example.
- There are seemingly no other direct hardware/virtualization adapters for running installs from storage media.
- I can't install a dist from inside an existing WSL by unpacking it, or similar, at least I've not come up with a solution for it.

The solution doesn't have to be a one-liner, any complexity is accepted and appreciated.

Comment: Why not install the real Linux distribution via boot media ?

Comment: Because I use Windows, but develop in WSL. I have linux already on several machines, but that's not related to the question I'm asking.

Comment: WSL not in a vhdx file is a contradiction. WSL is Hyper-V and the vhdx is a virtual machine. You can install the distro on an external disk, but that only means that the vhdx will reside there.

Comment: Alright, I thought VHDX was a file format for a virtual harddrive, especially since it's not just used for virtualization. You can learn more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_(file_format). You can also mount ext4 drives to WSL.

Comment: WSL is too limited as a virtual machine product. You need the real Hyper-V or VMware or VirtualBox to use a physical drive as the installation media. But why do you care about WSL when the Linux distribution is what you're working in.

Comment: You can probably turn that into an answer, as I've really tried and not found any evidence that there's any way around it either except for writing custom driver.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSL not in a vhdx file is a contradiction. WSL is Hyper-V and the
vhdx is a virtual machine. You can install the Linux distribution
on an external disk, but that only means that the vhdx will reside there.

WSL is too limited as a virtual machine product. You need the real
Hyper-V or VMware or VirtualBox to use a physical drive as the
installation media.